# In the Graphql I need to display list

Tags: .net, graphql

I would like to return the list of data, passing the id. Getting below error Graphql

{
"errorMessage": [
"System.InvalidOperationException: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GraphQLAPI.Domain.PatientInfo]\" value of type \"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GraphQLAPI.Domain.PatientInfo]" is not allowed for "PatientType". Either change IsTypeOf method of "PatientType" to accept this value or return another value from your resolver.\r\n   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ValidateNodeResult(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node) in /*/src/GraphQL/Execution/ExecutionStrategy.cs:line 404\r\n   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.CompleteNode(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node) in /*/src/GraphQL/Execution/ExecutionStrategy.cs:line 316"
]
}

public class PatientQuery: ObjectGraphType
{
PatientInfoService infoService = new PatientInfoService();

```
    public PatientQuery()
    {
        Field<PatientDetailsType>(
            name: "patient",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "patientid" }),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var id = context.GetArgument<int>("patientid");
                return infoService.GetPatientById(id);
            }
            );
    }

}
```

infoservice.GetPatientBYid(id) return list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that infoService.GetPatientById() returns a list the following change will reflect that in the resolver.

This line:

```
...
Field<PatientDetailsType>(
...
```

To:

```
...
Field<ListGraphType<PatientDetailsType>>(
...
```